# Invalid syntax when running multiple lines of code in an if statement

Tags: python

Very, very simplified version of my code for readability

```
myList = {"object1","object2","object3"}
myString = "object4"

if myString in myList: {
  print("Hello,")
  print("World!")
}
```

The first print works, but the second returns a syntax error?
I feel weird asking such a simple question on this site but I can't find any search results for something similar so I think I may just be an idiot that needs something obvious pointed out.

More than one line of code executed in the if statement causes a syntax error.

Comment: Python doesn't use braces to surround code blocks.

Comment: As a humorous aside, you can try to ask the interpreter to enable braces as an optional feature using `from __future__ import braces`.

Comment: Also, `myList` is a set, not a list.

Comment: Learn about indentation here : https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Comment: As above, remove the braces and this will work. Technically it would also work if you place a comma after the first print statement, too... (but not advised)

Comment: @R3uben True, but gross :)

Comment: @R3uben That actually raises an interesting point, as it's not the braces themselves, but the context, that causes the error. I've added a discussion of that trick to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't have braces to delimit blocks of codes; it uses *only* indentation.

```
if myString in myList:
    print("Hello,")
    print("World!")
```

---

A comment suggested adding a comma:

```
if myString in myList: {
    print("Hello,"),
    print("World!")
}
```

This "works", but only because you used expression statements for the body of the `if` statement. The body requires a sequence of one or more statements; one type of statement is the expression statement (one that consists of a single expression). Because `print` is a function, the braces can be parsed as defining a set display, one that evaluates to the set `{None, None}` at run-time. As such, it is valid body for the `if` statement.

If you were to try this with any other kind of statement, you would continue to get a syntax error, the exact error depending on what statements you tried to use and how much you confuse the parser in the process.